# Синтаксическая ошибка

Tags: синтаксис

*Заходя в магазин или на рынок, чтобы купить продукты, мы часто не только думаем о стоимости, но и о качестве товаров.*

Где в этом предложении нарушены нормы построения предложений с однородными членами ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В исходном предложении "не только... но и" должно объединять однородные
сочетания "о стоимости" и "о качестве", но из-за нарушения порядка слов под действие оборота подпало сказуемое "думаем". Правильно: "... мы часто думаем не только о стоимости, но и о качестве товаров".

Answer (score 0):

Alex_ander прав. Но как вариант, можно считать, что во второй части пропало сказуемое.

*Заходя в магазин или на рынок, чтобы купить продукты, мы часто не только думаем о стоимости, но и задумываемся (рассуждаем, догадываемся)  о качестве товаров.*

Тоже будет верным. Наряду с вариантов в уже принятом ответе.